Consolidate Excel File with Images and Write the Output with the Image into Excel in R
I am trying to consolidate two excel file with the same column names and write the output into an another excel file while keeping the images in place.
But whenever I consolidate the output, the images are not visible as its not being read into the data frame. Can this be done in R? Or is it not possible?
I am aware that there is a another question (Is there a way to extract a picture from an excel file using R? It could then be placed into the tesseract ocr) which is similar, please keep in mind that the answer to that is not a solution to this question. It does not explain anything about consolidation of multiple data frames and how to write the output. So the question is different.
Attached is the code:
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

Book1 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/X/X/Desktop/Book1.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

Book2 <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/X/X/Desktop/Book1.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet2")

Consolidation <- rbind(Book1,Book2)
print(Consolidation)

writexl::write_xlsx(Consolidation,"C:/Users/X/X/Desktop/Consolidation.xlsx")

Attached is the dataframe Book1:
structure(list(`SL#` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ITEM = c("ABC963", "ABC596", 
"ABC410", "ABC816", "ABC851"), COLOR = c(42, 26, 39, 15, 13), 
    `ITEM DESC` = c("ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC3", "ABC4", "ABC5"), 
    `COLOR DESC` = c("CLR1", "CLR2", "CLR3", "CLR4", "CLR5"), 
    SIZE = c("S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"), IMAGE = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), COST = c(88, 63, 25, 78, 99), PLACE = c("BAR", "DEL", 
    "RMA", "MCI", "MAN"), TIME = structure(c(1733011200, 1735689600, 
    1738368000, 1740787200, 1743465600), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Attached is the data frame Book2:
structure(list(`SL#` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ITEM = c("XYZ938", "XYZ412", 
"XYZ573", "XYZ561", "XYZ932"), COLOR = c(80, 83, 76, 81, 81), 
    `ITEM DESC` = c("XYZ1", "XYZ2", "XYZ3", "XYZ4", "XYZ5"), 
    `COLOR DESC` = c("CLR11", "CLR12", "CLR13", "CLR14", "CLR15"
    ), SIZE = c("S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"), IMAGE = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), COST = c(88, 63, 25, 78, 99), PLACE = c("BAR", 
    "DEL", "RMA", "MCI", "MAN"), TIME = structure(c(1746057600, 
    1748736000, 1751328000, 1754006400, 1756684800), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Adding images for better visual clarity:
Book1: 
Book2: 
The Expected Output : 

read_excel only reads in the data.

I don't see how this question is a duplicate. Sure there is a common denominator of reading excel file with images. But the purpose and output is completely different. Reopen the file. I have struggled with doing this so I am curious about the answer.

Short answer: I'm not aware that what you want to do is currently possible in R (at least not with openxlsx). Long answer: here I show how it is possible.

@JanMarvin In the real example where I am trying to implement this, I have 6 excel files with 150 lines in each of them. As per the github solution, I would have to write in each and overline individually right. Which is not a practical solution right.

EDIT: There is probably a better way to get the image dimensions. I just got them by messing with format picture. All you are doing is looping over the insertImage. Like this
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

wb = loadWorkbook('examp.xlsx')

wb2 = loadWorkbook('examp copy.xlsx')

wb_big = createWorkbook()

dt = readxl::read_xlsx('examp.xlsx')

dt2 = readxl::read_xlsx('examp copy.xlsx')

data_to_add = bind_rows(dt, dt2)

get_images = wb@.xData$media


get_images_two = wb2@.xData$media

img = c(get_images, get_images_two)

addWorksheet(wb_big, 'data')

for (i in seq_along(img)) {
    insertImage(wb_big, sheet = 'data', file = img[i], startCol = 7, startRow = i + 1,
            height = 0.2, width = 0.71)    
}

saveWorkbook(wb_big, 'example_two.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)

Created on 2024-09-19 with reprex v2.1.1
You can do this using openxlsx. You may have to do a little fiddling to get the placement of the data/image in the right place.
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


big_data = bind_rows(sheet1, sheet2)

p = ggplot(starwars, aes(x = mass, y = height)) +
  geom_point()

ggsave('plot.png')

wb = createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "data")

insertImage(wb, "data", "plot.png")

writeData(wb, "data", x = big_data , startCol = 1, startRow = 15)

saveWorkbook(wb, 'exampworkbook.xlsx', overwrite = TRUE)

Created on 2024-09-18 with reprex v2.1.0

Unfortunately the code doesn't work. I think we misunderstood each other, I have adjusted the code to visually share the expected output. Can you please have a look and adjust the code accordingly.

Can you relook at the file, the answer is not accurate

The code does not work. As it just have consolidated images and has no data frame next to it. And the consolidated image is also not fully accurate as the output has random image in the middle.

Huh interesting. I got it to work with the stock images in excel. You may want to reach out to the openxlsx folks for some guidance on this.

How do I reach out to openxlsx folks? In my output, it had no dataframe just 9 images where there was 10 images in the file. And out of the 9 images which were consolidated, 2 of them was not even in the file which we read from.

You can file an issue on their github.
